# How can I make git status --short be the default

Tags: git

I can use
`git status` to see a verbose listing (also `git status --verbose`) and
`git status --short` to see a short listing.

How I can I change
`git status --short` be the *default* instead of the current default of `git status --verbose`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this related stack overflow answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927672/how-can-i-get-git-status-to-always-use-short-format

It looks like the best option would be making an alias, so you could type `git s`
to get the short listing instead of `git status --short` and then just use `git status` for the `--verbose` listing.

```
git config --global alias.s 'status --short'
```

Comment: Other people mentioned making a shell script called `gits` that executed `git status --short`; I guess that would save you one keystroke :P

Answer (score 2):

In 2012 when this was asked, the [alias proposed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38128/1925) was the best option. Since 2013 however there is something better:

```
$ git config status.short true
```

This will configure Git so that `git status` will show short output by default. The usual rules about global, user, and project config files apply.